# Add hover text to boxplot in plolty using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I´ve gone thourgh some exemples but couldn´t fix the hover text

Here is a minimal exemple:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

newhovertext=paste0(iris$Species,"<br>",iris$Sepal.Width)
g <- ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Width,label=newhovertext)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5) 
 plotly::ggplotly(g,tooltip=label)
```

applying the above code will result in the following image:

[image]

I can´t display the plant names in the hover text, would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(datasets)
data(iris)

newhovertext=paste0(iris$Species,"<br>",iris$Sepal.Width)
g<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Width, label=newhovertext))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5)
g %>% ggplotly()
```

then it shows the labels while hovering, for more advanced solution you should consider using `shiny`.

you can see the resulted plot in: http://rpubs.com/david_sriker/555513

a different solution which you will see the other values:

```
gg_box <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width, text=paste("Species:",Species, "\n",
                                             "Width:", Sepal.Width))) +
  geom_boxplot()+

  #invisible layer of points
  geom_point(alpha = 0)

gg_box %>%
  ggplotly()
```

and you can see the resulted plot in: http://rpubs.com/david_sriker/555522

Comment: Not working for me with plotly 4.9.1. It´s a simple report that i´m running , no need for shiny.

Comment: A screenshot of the image you have upload.
[Your image](https://imge.to/i/vdGT1s)

Comment: @david please see the other link